# Implementing a JMS consumer

Tags: java, producer-consumer, jms

I need a standalone client that consumes messages from the queue every time a message exists. I already have set-up an ActiveMQ queue named `hello.world`.

**ConsumerClient.java**

```
public class ConsumerClient {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Consumer("tcp://localhost:61616", "hello.world"));
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private String brokerUrl;
    private String queueName;
    private boolean isRunning;

    public Consumer(String brokerUrl, String queueName) {
        this.brokerUrl = brokerUrl;
        this.queueName = queueName;
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        while (isRunning) {

            System.out.println("Listening for messages...");

            Connection connection = null;
            MessageConsumer consumer = null;
            Session session = null;

            try {

                //Create a connection factory 
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);

                //Create a connection 
                connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
                        System.out.println("JMS Exception occurred...");
                    }
                });


                //Create a session
                session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                //Create destination
                Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

                //Create consumer
                consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

                //Start the connection
                connection.start();

                Message message = consumer.receive();
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    try {
                        //Persist message to database
                        //...some code that persists message to database
                        session.commit();
                    } catch (Exception e) { 
                        //Persistence failed
                        session.rollback();
                    }
                }


            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (consumer != null)
                    try {
                        consumer.close();
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                if (session != null)
                    try {
                        session.close();
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                if (connection != null)
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to use a `MessageListener` instead (honestly, I don't know where the `MessageListener` would fit in my code since if I remove `MessageConsumer.receive()` and added my own listener, my application hangs since there's no synchronous blocking). We're planning to have at least two of these consumers up just in case one fails.

Is this best practice? We don't use JNDI and I feel that Apache Camel would be too much for a simple process like this.

Should I be creating a deployable .war file instead?

Comment: Why would you want a *.war file? A JAR file can be run standalone too... Also, are you on Java 6/7/8?

Comment: By "every time a message exists" do you mean in real time?

Comment: Is there a business rule against the application hanging? Why are you tryng to achieve blocking? You can set message IDs if you're interested in specific messages.

Comment: @dev_feed Yes, real time.

Comment: @h.j.k I don't really know the best practice with regards to standalone apps. Seeing that we run all our projects in a servlet container, I was wondering if a .war could be suitable for this.

Comment: @dev_feed I'm trying to achieve blocking because if I don't block anything out and just use a MessageListener, the application freezes since I guess it keeps on recreating the Connection,Session,Producer objects

Comment: @MiguelPortugal I think you're right, then.  Do you intend to process the messages in the other war applications? If so, you can just register your connection and message listener when you start your server. ActiveMQ would handle the rest.

Comment: @dev_feed Basically, I have a Struts web app and inside it, a service that would act as a producer to create messages and send them to the queue. Since we run everything on Tomcat, I was thinking about creating a web-app with a Listener class that implements a MessageListener that can be responsible for consuming the messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25417/discussion-between-miguel-portugal-and-dev-feed).

Comment: That's exactly how we decided to do it for our web apps that use ActiveMQ.  The listeners have worked great for real time processing!

Answer (score 1):

> a standalone client that consumes messages from the queue every time a message exists

If you want to process the messages in real time, implementing a message listener is the most practical way -- this way you let ActiveMQ and JMS handle the continuous checking that you're currently doing. As you said, you could do this in a WAR, but a JAR, or thread could accomplish the same task.

If you weren't implementing runnable and coding inside your current `while (isRunning) {` loop, your current setup would be more appropriate for retrieving one message at a specific time.  Since you are, you're basically telling the JVM to create a connection, create a session, retrieve one message, kill everything, and start over.  This just adds a ton of overhead best left to the API.